# HTML5 Href "sms" content with break line tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I want to use html link href to text message(sms) in android smart phone.But i try want the breakline in my message content.I have to display my message in messengers like below

"adgsd

sdgsf

asdfdf"

I try use "< br >","< br/ >","/n","/r" also cant break line.

Any Idea?Below is sample code with replace the < br > to other tag.

```
  link = "smsto:" + "601" + "?body=" + document.getElementById("DetailContent").innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
  document.getElementById("smsDetailLink1").setAttribute("href", link);
```

Comment: Try `%0D%0A` it's how you do it for `mailto:`

Answer (score 4):

"%0D%0A"

with this format can get break line.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the answers given above are just the hex ASCII codes for the DOS/Windows line ending CR-LF (\r\n), i.e. carriage return and line feed. A lot of you probably knew that, some may not.